# How to change the cell font back to normal mode from code (in editing mode) in Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

This is how the cell used to look like before I enter the command mode using esc key.
[How I want the cell to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlWgK.png)

But after I enter the cell and make edits it starts to look like this [How the cell looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WnfB.png)

What can I do to make it look like normal font?

(By normal font I mean non code font like not the mark up font)

EDIT: Yes when I press the run button it does change back into normal font but I don't want to run/load the page every time. Is there any shortcut by which I can change from markdown command mode to normal mode?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I understand your question, you just need to execute the cell (play button), then the markdown will be interpreted and the cell looks like you intended.